# How do I make a variable visible anywhere in a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

CurrentlyGrounded Should flip to true and false. Instead, visual studio is reporting that it "Doesn't exist in the current context". How do I force this variable to exist EVERYWHERE in the script?

Making it public did absolutely nothing.

The problem occurs in the private void GroundCheck() method on Line 267.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (Rigidbody))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CapsuleCollider))]
    public class RigidbodyFirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class MovementSettings
        {
            public float ForwardSpeed = 8.0f;   // Speed when walking forward
            public float BackwardSpeed = 4.0f;  // Speed when walking backwards
            public float StrafeSpeed = 4.0f;    // Speed when walking sideways

            public float AirForwardSpeed = 8.0f;   // Speed when flying forward
            public float AirBackwardSpeed = 4.0f;  // Speed when flying backwards
            public float AirStrafeSpeed = 4.0f;    // Speed when flying sideways

            public bool CurrentlyGrounded = true;

            public float RunMultiplier = 2.0f;   // Speed when sprinting
            public KeyCode RunKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;
            public float JumpForce = 30f;
            public AnimationCurve SlopeCurveModifier = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(-90.0f, 1.0f), new Keyframe(0.0f, 1.0f), new Keyframe(90.0f, 0.0f));
            [HideInInspector] public float CurrentTargetSpeed = 8f;

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            private bool m_Running;
#endif

            public void UpdateDesiredTargetSpeed(Vector2 input)
            {
                if (input == Vector2.zero) return;
                if (input.x > 0 || input.x < 0 && CurrentlyGrounded == true)
                {
                    //strafe
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = StrafeSpeed;
                }
                else if (input.x > 0 || input.x < 0 && CurrentlyGrounded == false)
                {
                    //strafe
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = AirStrafeSpeed;
                }
                if (input.y < 0 && CurrentlyGrounded == true)
                {
                    //backwards
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = BackwardSpeed;
                }
                else if (input.y < 0 && CurrentlyGrounded == false)
                {
                    //backwards
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = AirBackwardSpeed;
                }
                if (input.y > 0 && CurrentlyGrounded == true)
                {
                    //forwards
                    //handled last as if strafing and moving forward at the same time forwards speed should take precedence
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = ForwardSpeed;
                }
                else if (input.y > 0 && CurrentlyGrounded == false)
                {
                    //forwards
                    //handled last as if strafing and moving forward at the same time forwards speed should take precedence
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = AirForwardSpeed;
                }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
                if (Input.GetKey(RunKey))
                {
                    CurrentTargetSpeed *= RunMultiplier;
                    m_Running = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_Running = false;
                }
#endif
            }

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            public bool Running
            {
                get { return m_Running; }
            }
#endif
        }


        [Serializable]
        public class AdvancedSettings
        {
            public float groundCheckDistance = 0.01f; // distance for checking if the controller is grounded ( 0.01f seems to work best for this )
            public float stickToGroundHelperDistance = 0.5f; // stops the character
            public float slowDownRate = 20f; // rate at which the controller comes to a stop when there is no input
            public bool airControl; // can the user control the direction that is being moved in the air
            [Tooltip("set it to 0.1 or more if you get stuck in wall")]
            public float shellOffset; //reduce the radius by that ratio to avoid getting stuck in wall (a value of 0.1f is nice)
        }


        public Camera cam;
        public MovementSettings movementSettings = new MovementSettings();
        public MouseLook mouseLook = new MouseLook();
        public AdvancedSettings advancedSettings = new AdvancedSettings();


        private Rigidbody m_RigidBody;
        private CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
        private float m_YRotation;
        private Vector3 m_GroundContactNormal;
        private bool m_Jump, m_PreviouslyGrounded, m_Jumping, m_IsGrounded;


        public Vector3 Velocity
        {
            get { return m_RigidBody.velocity; }
        }

        public bool Grounded
        {
            get { return m_IsGrounded; }
        }

        public bool Jumping
        {
            get { return m_Jumping; }
        }

        public bool Running
        {
            get
            {
 #if !MOBILE_INPUT
                return movementSettings.Running;
#else
                return false;
#endif
            }
        }


        private void Start()
        {
            m_RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
            mouseLook.Init (transform, cam.transform);
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            RotateView();

            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = true;
            }
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            GroundCheck();
            Vector2 input = GetInput();

            if ((Mathf.Abs(input.x) > float.Epsilon || Mathf.Abs(input.y) > float.Epsilon) && (advancedSettings.airControl || m_IsGrounded))
            {
                // always move along the camera forward as it is the direction that it being aimed at
                Vector3 desiredMove = cam.transform.forward*input.y + cam.transform.right*input.x;
                desiredMove = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desiredMove, m_GroundContactNormal).normalized;

                desiredMove.x = desiredMove.x*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed;
                desiredMove.z = desiredMove.z*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed;
                desiredMove.y = desiredMove.y*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed;
                if (m_RigidBody.velocity.sqrMagnitude <
                    (movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed))
                {
                    m_RigidBody.AddForce(desiredMove*SlopeMultiplier(), ForceMode.Impulse);
                }
            }

            if (m_IsGrounded)
            {
                m_RigidBody.drag = 5f;

                if (m_Jump)
                {
                    m_RigidBody.drag = 0f;
                    m_RigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(m_RigidBody.velocity.x, 0f, m_RigidBody.velocity.z);
                    m_RigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, movementSettings.JumpForce, 0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
                    m_Jumping = true;
                }

                if (!m_Jumping && Mathf.Abs(input.x) < float.Epsilon && Mathf.Abs(input.y) < float.Epsilon && m_RigidBody.velocity.magnitude < 1f)
                {
                    m_RigidBody.Sleep();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_RigidBody.drag = 0f;
                if (m_PreviouslyGrounded && !m_Jumping)
                {
                    StickToGroundHelper();
                }
            }
            m_Jump = false;
        }


        private float SlopeMultiplier()
        {
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(m_GroundContactNormal, Vector3.up);
            return movementSettings.SlopeCurveModifier.Evaluate(angle);
        }


        private void StickToGroundHelper()
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_Capsule.radius * (1.0f - advancedSettings.shellOffset), Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                                   ((m_Capsule.height/2f) - m_Capsule.radius) +
                                   advancedSettings.stickToGroundHelperDistance, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Angle(hitInfo.normal, Vector3.up)) < 85f)
                {
                    m_RigidBody.velocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(m_RigidBody.velocity, hitInfo.normal);
                }
            }
        }


        private Vector2 GetInput()
        {

            Vector2 input = new Vector2
                {
                    x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
                    y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical")
                };
            movementSettings.UpdateDesiredTargetSpeed(input);
            return input;
        }


        private void RotateView()
        {
            //avoids the mouse looking if the game is effectively paused
            if (Mathf.Abs(Time.timeScale) < float.Epsilon) return;

            // get the rotation before it's changed
            float oldYRotation = transform.eulerAngles.y;

            mouseLook.LookRotation (transform, cam.transform);

            if (m_IsGrounded || advancedSettings.airControl)
            {
                // Rotate the rigidbody velocity to match the new direction that the character is looking
                Quaternion velRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(transform.eulerAngles.y - oldYRotation, Vector3.up);
                m_RigidBody.velocity = velRotation*m_RigidBody.velocity;
            }
        }

        /// sphere cast down just beyond the bottom of the capsule to see if the capsule is colliding round the bottom
        private void GroundCheck()
        {
            m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_IsGrounded;
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_Capsule.radius * (1.0f - advancedSettings.shellOffset), Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                                   ((m_Capsule.height/2f) - m_Capsule.radius) + advancedSettings.groundCheckDistance, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                m_IsGrounded = true;
                CurrentlyGrounded = true;
                m_GroundContactNormal = hitInfo.normal;
            }
            else
            {
                m_IsGrounded = false;
                CurrentlyGrounded = false;
                m_GroundContactNormal = Vector3.up;
            }
            if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && m_IsGrounded && m_Jumping)
            {
                m_Jumping = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should be happening is that it's seen and changes as expected.

Instead, it's reported as nonexisting in the current context.

Comment: You can mark it as `static` and use it as `MovementSettings.CurrentlyGrounded = true;`

Comment: How would I go about implementing such changes?

Comment: Change `public bool CurrentlyGrounded = true;` in the `MovementSettings` class to `public static bool CurrentlyGrounded = true;` and change all the usages of `CurrentlyGrounded` to `MovementSettings.CurrentlyGrounded` BUT ONLY when using outside of the `MovementSettings` class.

Comment: While the script compiles, it is no longer able to dynamically switch between true and false. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** listen to people who want to make everything `static` just to access stuff "more easily".

This actually might cause a lot of trouble as soon as you have more than exactly one instances of that class (e.g. if there are two players, or an AI uses the same component).

Another bad side effect is that you won't be able anymore to configure it via the Inspector e.g. for debugging or to give it the desired start value.

---

What you want to use instead is

```
moventSettings.CurrentlyGrounded
```

to access the value of your `MovementSettings` instance.

Just the same way you did it e.g. in

```
movementSettings.Running
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a global variable.

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static String value = "Sample Value"; // Modifiable
    public static readonly String CODE_PREFIX = "TEST-"; // Unmodifiable
}
```

You can then retrieve the defined values anywhere in your code

```
String code = Globals.CODE_PREFIX + value.ToString();
```

Comment: 1. the question was about a `bool` value...  2. why even introduce a new dedicated class if you simply can make the value `static`? 3. Do **not** use `static` everywhere just because you don't know how to access the correct instance (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55565711/7111561)). This causes more problems (in long term) than it solves (in short term).